# find end of line after another in text file in Python

Tags: python, text, replace

**Issue**

Hello all,

in a text file i need to replace an unknown string by another,

first to find it i need to find the line before it 'name Blur2'
as there is many line beginnig by 'xpos':

```
 name Blur2
 xpos 12279             # 12279 is the end of line to find and put in a variable
```

**Code to get unknow string:**

```
#string to find:
keyString = ' name Blur2'
f2 = open("output_file.txt", 'w+') 
with open("input_file.txt", 'r+') as f1:
    lines = f1.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        if keyString in line:
            nextLine = lines[i + 1]       
            print ' nextLine: ',nextLine  #result:  nextLine:   xpos 12279
            number = nextLine.rsplit(' xpos ', 1)[1]
            print ' number: ',number  #result: number:  12279
            #convert string to float:
            newString = '{0}\n'.format(int(number)+ 10)
            print ' newString: ',newString    #result: newString:  12289
            f2.write("".join([nextLine.replace(number, str(newString))]))  #this line isn't working
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

so, i had completely change of method but the last line: f2.write...  isn't working as expected, did someone know why?

thanks again for your help :)

Comment: 5 last characters `line[-5:]`

Comment: process all lines, copy when not containing search string `Blur2`, if contains `Blur2` set boolean, if boolean set on next line do replace and reset boolean. Also use context managers: `with open("last_file.txt", 'r+') as f1:`

Comment: thanks, the method:   line[-5:]is is working perfect with my code:  f2.write("".join([i.replace(i[-10:], newPad) if keyString in i else i for i in f1.readlines()]))

Comment: for the replace, unfortunatly i need to record it before replace and i don't know how, i'm trying to get it with a split actually...

Comment: don't start a variable with a Capital, in Python convention that are Class names

Comment: arf sorry, i didn't knew that, i'm gone change it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

regex seems like it would help, https://regex101.com/.

Regex searches a string with a language that defines a pattern. I listed the most important ones for learning the pattern itself, but it is sometimes a better alternative than python's native string manipulation.

You first describe the pattern that you will be using, then actually compile the pattern. For the string check, I defined it as a raw string using r''. This means I don't have to escape a \ within a string (example: printing \ would be print('\') instead of print(r'').

There are a couple of parts to this regex.

\s for whitespace(characters like space, ' ')

\n or \r for newline and carriage return, [^] defines which characters not to look for (so [^\n\r] searches for anything not containing a newline or carriage return), the * indicates it can have 0 or more of the characters indicated. $ in the regex string accounts for everything before the line end.

so the pattern searches for 'name Blur2' specifically with any number of whitespaces afterwards and a newline. The parentheses allow this to be group 1 (explained later). The second part '([^\n\r]*$)' captures any number of characters that aren't a newline or carriage return up until the end of that line.

Groups account for the parentheses, so '(name blue\n)' is group 1, and the line you want replaced '([^\n\r]*$)' is group 2. checkre.sub should replace the whole text with group 1
and the new string, so it replaces the first line with the first line, and replaces the second line with your new string

```
import re
check = r'(name Blur2\s*\n)([^\n\r]*$)'
checkre = re.compile(check, re.MULTILINE)
checkre.sub(\g<1>+newstring, file)
```

You need to set re.MULTILINE since you're checking multiple lines, if the '\n' isn't matched, you could use [\n\r\z] which gets one of either end of the line, carriage return, or absolute end of the string.

rioV8's comment works, but you could also use '.{5}$', which accounts for any 5 characters before the end of the line. It could be helpful within a re

It should be possible to get the old string with

```
oldstring = checkre.search(filestring).group(1)
```

I have not played with span yet, but

```
stringmatch = checkre.search(filestring)
oldstring = stringmatch.group(2)
newfilestring = filestring[0:stringmatch.span[0]] + stringmatch.group(1) + newstring + filestring[stringmatch.span[1]]:]
```

should be pretty close to what you're looking for, although the splice may not be exactly correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i doesn't understand when i record string :12279 ?  i need to record it because later i'm gone use it in a math formula and write it in another line...

Comment: i'm gone edit my question i think i haven't been very explicit, may be i need to split 'xpos ' in the ligne after name Blur2 to get the number?

Comment: I may try to edit this eventually to answer the question. Regex can definitely find what you need, and it can also replace it. The second group will return the string ('oldstring=checkre.search(file).group(2)' I think), but replacing the string in the file without searching again will take some editing/research. I have no idea what the comparison speed is currently, but it wouldn't be optimal.

Comment: yes, indeed i don't really understand this method, i you have the time to to edit it, i will be very glad, thanks anyway for the answer!

Comment: I edited this a little, but I may try a different answer later in the week. What you have now is fairly close (without using regex), but I can't see where you're writing the lines that don't need to be replaced to the new file. I'll try and spend some time playing around with it later in the week.

Answer (score 0):

The initial program was pretty close. I edited a little bit of it to tweak a few things that were wrong.

You weren't initially writing the lines that needed to be replaced, I'm not sure why you needed to join things. Just replacing the number directly seemed to work. Python doesn't allow changes to the i in a for loop, and you need to skip one line so it isn't written to the file, so I changed it to a while loop. Anyway ask any questions you have, but the below code seems to work.

```
#string to find:
keyString = ' name Blur2'
f2 = open("output_file.txt", 'w+') 
with open("test.txt", 'r+') as f1:
    lines = f1.readlines()
    i=0
    while i <len(lines):
        line = lines[i]
        if keyString in line:
            f2.write(line)
            nextLine = lines[i + 1]
            #end of necessary 'i' calls, increment i to avoid reprinting writing the replaced line string
            i+=1
            print (' nextLine: ',nextLine  )#result:  nextLine:   xpos 12279
            number = nextLine.rsplit(' xpos ', 1)[1]
            #as was said in a comment, this coula also be number = nextLine[-5:]
            print (' number: ',number  )#result: number:  12279
            #convert string to float:
            newString = '{0}\n'.format(int(number)+ 10)
            print (' newString: ',newString)    #result: newString:  12289
            f2.write(nextLine.replace(number, str(newString)))  #this line isn't working
        else:
            f2.write(line)
        i+=1
f1.close()
f2.close()
```